# Bat File return code to fire off a task w/ task scheduler?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible for the windows task scheduler to read the return code of a batch script and to fire off a task based on the value of said return code? I have a batch script that:

- copies files from one drive in server A to another drive in server B.
- If server B is down it'll complete with a return code 1
- and I want the task scheduler to see that return code of 1 and send an email saying there's something wrong with server B.

It's clear in the task scheduler it sees the return codes but I can't seem to find an option to use the return code.

Another idea I've thought about is have the task scheduler send an email if a task fails after starting up. But it appears even when the batch file returns a 1 for a failed copy, the task scheduler still marks the task as `ran successfully.`

Comment: At the end of your batch file just check the error level and use `SCHTASKS.exe` to run the task you need to.

Comment: @Squashman, I'll look into SCHTASKS, thanks. Is this something I have to install?

Comment: It is the console application that accesses all your scheduled tasks.

Comment: Are you still using `DOS`? The OS from the 80s/90s. I think you are using Windows. And do you mean `CMD` instead of `DOS`?